# Proving the principle of weak induction, using strong induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, induction

I am struggling to figure out what exactly the claim that I am proving should be. I want to use the principle of strong induction to show that weak induction holds, where weak induction is the principle that for some predicate $P$, if $P(0)$ and $\forall n, P(n) \implies P(n+1)$, then $\forall n, P(n)$ and strong induction is where if $P(0)$ and if $\forall n, \forall k \space s.t \space k < n, P(k)$, then $P(n)$. What is the predicate that I should be using in my proof by strong induction? How do I proceed?

Comment: The exact same predicate $P$. The hard one is proving the other direction.

Comment: Also, you haven't quite phrased strong induction accurately. You're mixing up two distinct principles. One is well-ordering induction, which states that if $\forall n, (\forall k < n, P(k)) \to P(n)$, then $\forall n, P(n)$. The other is strong induction, which states that if $P(0)$ and also $\forall n, (\forall k \leq n, P(k)) \to P(n + 1)$, then $\forall n P(n)$.

Comment: @MarkSaving: I don't think there is any agreement on what "strong induction" means. The traditional name for what you call "well-ordering induction" and what many people call "strong induction" is "course-of-values induction" and the principle it names does not require a base case to be proved.

Comment: @MarkSaving is the idea to prove that if some arbitrary predicate can be proven by strong induction, then it can be proven by weak induction? My original approach was to try to prove the principle of weak induction itself. In the latter case I wasn't sure what to induct on, but in the former case it should just be $n$, right?

Comment: @RobArthan That may be true. But it is certainly true that OP is mixing the two principles at hand up, whatever you call them, since $P(0)$ is not necessary to assume given that $\forall n, (\forall k < n, P(k)) \to P(n)$.

Comment: @noamchomsky You've gotten it exactly backwards; that would be proving strong induction using weak induction. Actually, it would technically be proving that strong induction is admissible and not proving strong induction itself, but that is not something you should concern yourself with.

Comment: @noamchomsky You should assume $P(0)$ and also assume that $\forall n , P(n) \to P(n + 1)$. Then, using strong induction, you should prove that $\forall n, P(n)$. Thus, you will prove weak induction using strong induction.

Comment: @MarkSaving I agree that the OP has mixed up two different induction principles.

Comment: As referenced [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction): *Complete(Strong) induction is equivalent to ordinary mathematical induction as described above, in the sense that a proof by one method can be transformed into a proof by the other. Suppose there is a proof of by complete induction. Let Q(n) mean "P(m) holds for all m such that 0<=m<=n". Then Q(n) holds for all n if and only if P(n) holds for all n, and our proof of P(n) is easily transformed into a proof of Q(n) by (ordinary) induction.*...

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to prove $P(0) \land (\forall x : P(x) \to P(x+1)) \to \forall n : P(n)$ by using the induction principle $I'$ :

> $(\forall x : (\forall y <x : P (y)) \to P (x)) \to \forall n : P(n) $

So to prove the implication we assume that $P(0)$ and $IH :=\forall x : P(x) \to P(x+1)$ are true and we are left to prove $\forall n : P(n)$. By $I'$ it now suffices to show $\forall x : (\forall y <x : P (y)) \to P (x)$.

For this, assume we have some $x$ and $\forall y < x : P (y)$ and try to prove $P(x)$.

- If $x = 0$ then $P(x)$ is $P(0)$ and therefore true.
- If $x > 0$ then we have $x -1 <x$ which gives us $P(x-1)$ by $\forall y < x : P (y)$. Using $IH$ this proves $P(x-1+1)$ which is of course $P(x)$.

So in every case we were able to prove $P(x)$ as desired. $~\Box$

---

Some bit of extra information: The case distinction is quite necessary, and one can see this by looking at the proof in first-order $\mathsf{PA}$. If we let $\mathsf{PA}^-$ designate the usual Peano axioms without the normal induction scheme $I$ and let $A:= \forall x : (x = 0 \lor \exists z : x = z + 1)$ then we have
$$
  (\mathsf{PA}^- + I) \, \vdash I' \land A  
  \hspace{2em} \text{and} \hspace{2em}  
  (\mathsf{PA}^- + I' + A) \,\vdash I  
$$
where $A$ is enabling the same kind of case distinction that was done in the above.
It is not possible to show $(\mathsf{PA}^- + I') \vdash I$ as $PA^- + I'$ has models which falsify $I$. We can get one such model by taking $\mathbb{N}$ and interpreting the symbol for the successor $S$ as the function $n \mapsto n + 2$. In a sense this creates two disjoint copies of $\mathbb{N}$, one starting with $0$ and containing all even numbers, and one starting with $1$ and containing all odd numbers. The usual induction can then only show that a predicate is true on all even numbers of the model and is therefore false.